# Looking for a word that has the meaning of "to work on something with doubled, extra effort"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word -- preferably a verb -- which has this meaning: "to work on something with doubled, extra effort"?

Ideally it should also express being desperate, not caring about the costs, willing to sacrifice absolutely anything to reach the goal.

Comment: Answers go down below guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***PLOW***
(figuratively)

According to *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:*

> - to proceed steadily and laboriously
>
> *had to plow through a stack of letters*.

According to  *Collin's Dictionary* :

> - To proceed in a slow, laborious, 
>     and steady manner (often followed by *through*):
>
> *The researcher plowed through a pile of reports*.

According to *Oxford Living Dictionary*:

> - Advance or progress laboriously or forcibly.
>
> ‘*the students are ploughing through a set of grammar exercises*’

These definitions and examples illustrate a typical linguistic phenomenon – the semantic development of the word.

In our case there is the so called 'meaning generalization'.

The name of the agricultural labor is metaphorically transferred to any labor (both physical and mental).

The transfer is based on the similarity of hard work, typical both for  peasants and other workers (including researchers).

Comment: This is not an answer according to our standards here because it contains no reasoning or explanation in your own words. Please read [this advice from SE’ss Community Management team](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and update this with your content.  We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the verb **[strive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strive)**:

**VERB**

> **1.** Make **great efforts** to achieve or obtain something. ‘national movements were **striving** for independence’ (Oxford)

In the definition quoted above, the phrase "great efforts" might suggest that the effort is doubled or extra.

Additionally, among the words like great, big, sublime, lofty, lordly and giant, here 'great' implies **"better than average"**. That's why it's absolutely correct to conclude (again) that the effort being/been made, is doubled or extra.

If this doesn't suit, there's a suitable phrase for what you want here: "[go the extra mile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-the-extra-mile)"

> to make more effort than is expected of you:

Comment: This is not an answer according to our standards here because it contains no reasoning or explanation in your own words. Please read [this advice from SE’ss Community Management team](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and update this with your content.  We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

**Venture** seems to meet some of your requirements; specifically, the implication you want of risk-taking. It's not an exact fit, though, because it doesn't readily imply extra effort.

> 1 *no object, with adverbial* Undertake a risky or daring journey or
>   course of action.
>
> 1.1 *with object* Expose to the risk of loss.

[[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/venture)]

Comment: This is not an answer according to our standards here because it contains no reasoning or explanation in your own words. Please read [this advice from SE’ss Community Management team](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and update this with your content.  We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.